# How to open and save image to resources

Tags: c#, resources, openfiledialog

What I have is when the user clicks a button, it opens a OpenFileDialog and when he opens a image I want to save it in the resources. How do I do this?

```
    private void btnAddObject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();

        fileDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.png) | *.png";

        fileDialog.ShowDialog();

        if(fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ResXResourceWriter.AddResource(fileDialog.FileName, );
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Resources;  
using System.Drawing;  
  
class Program  
{  
  static void Main(string[] args)  
  {  
    ResXResourceWriter rw = new ResXResourceWriter("Demo.resx");  
    using (Image image = Image.FromFile("logo.gif"))  
    {  
      rw.AddResource("WroxLogo", image);  
      rw.Close();        
    }  
  }  
}
```

Code taken from http://www.navioo.com/csharp/source_code/Add_image_Resource_313.html

Comment: Well I'm sure that works but what I'm trying to do is add a resource image to my existing Resources